# Does ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false remain set application-wide after setting it once?

Tags: c#, .net, class, assemblies, system.net

I have the following code:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

on my main windows form `frmMain_Load` event. I have many forms and classes where different web services are called but these are always called after completion of `frmMain_Load` event.

So, `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` will remain as set in all web service calls in all forms and classes? or do I have to set it to `false` on every web service call?

It is .NET 2.0 desktop application in C#.

Note: I am sorry I posted such a dumb question. I can check in debugger by setting a watch on that value.

Comment: Take a look into the Debugger and set a watch on that value and you will know.

Comment: Ohh. yes. I am sorry for posting a dumb question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer. but you can set the **expect100Continue** value to your **App.Config**.
Setting this will be applied to the all web service call. you don't need to set it on each webservice call separately.

put it inside Configuration->system.net->settings

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

**Note:** Do not change this settings unless you decided to ignore the **TCP 100Continue** response result.